# How do I generate reports in Jenkins if my shell script fails? Is there a plug in?

Tags: shell, jenkins, sh, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins job that will do a deployment in my CentOS machine by running the docker-compose file. This is how my shell script looks ?

```
    #!/bin/sh

# Post steps for deployment

# Navigate to deployment scripts
cd /deployment/scripts/v1.0.784

#Execute the uninstall script
./dit_undeploy_all.sh

set +e
#Remove all docker images and containers
docker container rm $(docker ps -a -q) -f
docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)
set -e

#Remove and clear out the folder structure
rm -rf *.*

#Gets all the latest files from Artifactory by reading from teh input file
wget -B https://artifactory.gue.com -i /deployment/scripts/inputFile.txt

# Gives rea/write access
chmod +x *.*

# Execute docker compose file to get all the latest containers
./dit_deploy_all.sh

#Add wait time for the services to be up and running
sleep 60s #Wait 15 sec

# Need to update the URL
./dit_create_policies.sh

#Verify URL Status Code of 200
cd /deployment/scripts

sleep 60s #Wait time 60s
./verifyHttpCode
```

The script ./verifyHttpCode does the following:

```
    #!/bin/bash
while read LINE; do
        curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}' "$LINE"
        echo " $LINE"
        done < url-list.txt
```

So basically after the deployment it will verify the http status code...What's the equivalent of testNG in shell script that I can use in Jenkins to verify the http status code and generate reports ??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this plugin : Audit2DB

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Audit+To+Database+Plugin

It will log all required job details into a DB. When you want to create a report, it will fetch it from DB.
So in this case, you'll need to fail the job (non-zero exit) on script failure. Also you can set $http_code as env variable on completion of your job and log the same into DB.